# Real performance of node.js

Tags: node.js

I've got a question concerning node.js performance.

There is quite lot of "benchmarks" and a lot of fuss about great performance of node.js. But how does it stand in real world? Not just process empty request at high speed.

If someone could try to compare this scenario:

Java (or equivalent) server running an application with complex business logic between receiving request and sending response.

How would node.js deal with it? If there was need for a lot of JavaScript processing on server side, is node.js really so fast that it can execute JavaScript, and stand a chance against more heavyveight competitors?

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357129/how-does-node-js-perform-compared-to-apache)?

Comment: @GoranJovic it's not a rant, it's a giant troll. Nothing that he says has any value.

Answer (score 6):

Node's kind of hard to compare directly because it's a bit of an odd bird. The critical thing to understand is that yes, while JS does block, which is intended desirable behavior in the case of Node, the other half of the system is the C++ operations under the hood that can in fact run in parallel with one another. That's the reason you do almost everything asynchronously with the JS in Node. The key thing to understand is that there are two layers. You direct traffic and handle simple data structures with the JS and its blocking nature acts as a kind of auto-queuing system. As a bonus, you get to reap all the benefits of JS being an obscenely easy language to implement messaging/event-driven paradigms with. For anything that's likely to take a while, no matter what you write it in, you're best off doing that with the C++.

The point of the JS as-blocking-interface on top of that is to bury all that nasty/messy thread-handling stuff WITHOUT actually reducing you to the use of one processor only.

People are no doubt going to write some absolutely hideously performing stuff with Node out of ignorance but I don't see any reason it couldn't scale for an enterprise(ew @ terminology)-level framework and I'm personally getting more and more excited about it the more I use it (which has so far mostly been to reduce config/build complexity of a web app triple-stack of Rails, .NET and Java).

Furthermore, modern JS JIT compilers have improved performance of JS by an order of magnitude in recent years and Node is built on Chrome's V8. I'd be surprised if JS didn't at least compare favorably to Python for single-threaded speed and like Python, you can handle the architectural glue of an app with a lot less code which tends to result in things being less messy and easier to manage in terms of basic work avoidance and writing a legible, modifiable, maintainable app, where you never have to think through what should (IMO) be obvious in higher level.

How do you really measure that semi-objectively for comparison? Barring some sort of competition with massive participation to write the same app with different stacks, you can't really. I think the best you can do is look at how apps tend to behave, what the team knows best, what tools are available, and not worry about performance comparisons unless the tool in question has a rep for crummy perf across the board. In my experience, Java wins the micro-benchmark wars, but is typically a notoriously poor performer on the server-side web compared to Rails, PHP, Python and ASP.net post-MVC for basic and not-so-basic web apps that I've worked on.

That's not to say Java couldn't outperform any app in another language or that it never does. Nor am I saying I've never seen shoddily written JS, Python, or PHP. However, given the quality of your average large Java team vs. a typically MUCH smaller team of JS or Python ninjas doing a web-app of average complexity for probably less total pay (and yes I'm absolutely offering a purely subjective opinion based on personal experience because that's all that's left) I'd put my money on an app produced by a few seasoned devs with a language that can get a lot more done in a lot fewer verbs and nouns without limiting your ability to structure things.

But ultimately, what I assume you're wanting to know is whether it's okay to use it and that involves subjective concerns.

So do you like the idea of writing apps with a given language/stack design, do you like what the community's doing with it, and barring more highly specific concerns does it not suck generally at performance in 80% of obvious use-cases? In Node's case, I'd personally say yes, yes, and yes.

But if you're not really interested in how it works and don't really care for JS, necessarily, I'd stay away from it because those are the two key things that give Node value and are requirements for keeping it performant.

So far for me, it's behaving exactly as I would expect a good JS tool to. It's reducing complexity like a champ by allowing me to wrap an inherently brittle/messy process in something that's robust and legible. That right there is why JS won the undisputed place it's had in browser UI and will continue to expand as a general-use language.

Answer (score 5):

Event-driven paradigms are inherently faster than multi-threaded paradigms because there is no context switching. While one "thread" is running, the rest are blocked until that thread hits a point where it no longer needs the processor (e.g. if it is waiting for a response from, say, the database). So you shouldn't be surprised if the benchmarks show that.

However, it does require that programmers know exactly what they're doing at a much lower level. If they don't release the waiting threads while the current thread is "waiting," it's suddenly going to be a lot less efficient than multi-threaded.

You should also bear in mind that practically no one will write a Node.js enterprise application, because actual coding efficiency would be low. They are more likely to write an enterprise application in one of [the many frameworks appearing that are built on top of Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-web-frameworks-full).

So you cannot fairly compare, say, Node.js to MVC for ASP.NET. You should compare it to something written directly in the .NET Framework.

Comment: So Node.js does, in fact, block sometimes?

Maybe I'm just taking their claims of "it doesn't block" too literally, but, as always the case with Cool Web Tech du Jour, I'm having a hard time picking out useful information from the hype.

Comment: Context switches aren't slow. How fast do you think a javascript function call is?

Comment: There is still context switching, it's just done at a much lower level for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Just noted you were speaking of event driven paradigm

Comment: @dan_waterworth Probably faster than you think by an order of magnitude if you haven't been paying attention for the last four years or so. IE8, I believe is the last non-JIT browser to be published that I'm aware of. Inline funcs locked in a specific scope can actually be performance enhancing over just repeating the statements inside them now because they can be cached.

Comment: @pdr yeah, I think context switching is more buried than eliminated. If Node wins perf battles, I suspect it's more to do with C++ and possibly decoupling of communication and multi-CPU file I/O than any inherent perf advantage of event-driven approaches.

Comment: @ErikReppen, having thought about this some more, you're right, a js function call is fast. In a tracing JIT, calls are even likely to be optimized away entirely. What is slow though, is heap allocating a closure for every other line of code and then garbage collecting these closures.

Comment: @dan_waterworth I'm pretty sure closures aren't impacting garbage collection when no references are actually bound within one. Every other line seems unlikely but yes, nobody's pretending JS is faster than C++ or even Java on a repeat the same one-liner 10,000 times comparison basis.

Comment: @ErikReppen, that's not quite what I'm saying. I'm saying CPS JS isn't as fast as direct style JS. To back this up, I've written a simple benchmark that calculates Fibonacci numbers inefficiently. The CPS version took 12 times longer that the one written in direct style, (full disclosure: I ended up using a trampolining style instead of standard CPS because JS lacks tail calls). It is common practice to write code that causes not empty closures to be created, look at the jQuery source for example. Every other line is obviously an exaggeration, but you can't deny that closures aren't common.

Comment: @dan_waterworth They certainly aren't uncommon but heavy usage suggests an over-reliance on global or global-style vars rather than things like context objects that are dropped into DOM event handlers automatically. Calculating Finbonacci sequences is a great example of precisely the sort of thing you shouldn't be doing with the messenger JS in a Node.js app. That should be left to a child process or a C++ bound operation. It's more the 99% use case scenarios of a typical server-side app where the JS is never going to get in its own way long enough to hold up things like file I/O.

Comment: @ErikReppen, There are two different types of state that you have in a callback. The state that associated with the event that triggered and state associated with the reason the callback was set at all. The second type is almost always necessary and unless it is stored in a global, it gets accessed via the closure's environment. I don't understand why you say that using closures causes over-reliance on globals when it does the opposite. The example I gave was just to show how much slower it is. I wouldn't expect people to write fibonacci like that, but they might write parsers in the same way.

Comment: "Event-driven paradigms are inherently faster than multi-threaded paradigms because there is no context switching."

It actually says all in one sentence.

Answer (score -1):

The benchmarks you refer to are exactly that. They are real world tests with fixed variables (hardware ect). Without those controlls the results will vary so much they will be meaningless

Comment: If true, a link would be useful.